# Websocket Request Routing with RxJava in Micronaut

Tags: websocket, rx-java, micronaut

I am implementing a WebSocket router in Micronaut which routes WebSocket text messages between WebSocket "Client" and WebSocket "Server" applications.
Each message is communicated topic id, which is part of url path /{topic}. Messages from same topic must be forwarded in both directions,
e.g. message for topic A is forwarded to topic A etc. [see architecture diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsH9J.png)

**WebSocket Routing**
So Client creates WebSocket connection to Router and after that Router creates connection to Server. This means that as soon as the Client creates connection to router, router must create connection to the Server.
For sending new messages in each direction Client -> Server or Server -> Client, existing connection for given topic must be reused.
The connections will be long-living with some retry reconnect logic I will incorporate later on.

**Message Sending Logic**
As soon as the Client sends message, it must be forwarded to the Server, same for reverse direction Server -> Client.

**Question**
Where I am stuck little bit is:

1. How can I use the Flowable api which Micronaut to forward messages from ServerHandler to ClientHandler and vice versa ?
   What I need is once that connection is estabilished, just keep information the connection is estabilished and simply forward the messsages between WebSocket handlers by using Rx Java api.

Originaly I implemented the forwarding logic by using a custom WebSocketSession cache and both ServerHandler and ClientHandler stored and retrieved
CompletableFuture from the cache. This approach worked and also solved asynchronous waiting for connected session,
but I would like to achieve the forwarding stuff in more stateless way by using pure RxJava Java patterns.
Another design flaw with using custom shared cache for sessions was that it was redundant to already existing session registry in Netty.

I have basic implementation of handlers for client and server, WebSocket handlers for Client/Server work so far,
but I don't know how to integrate the Flowable stuff properly.

**Source code ClientHandler:** (Handles WebSocket connection  from client to router)

```
@ServerWebSocket("/topic/{topicId}") public class ClientHandler {

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClientHandler.class);

private RxWebSocketClient webSocketClient;

private ConnectionProperties connectionProperties;

public ClientHandler(@Client("${connection.url}") RxWebSocketClient webSocketClient, ConnectionProperties connectionProperties) {
    this.webSocketClient = webSocketClient;
    this.connectionProperties = connectionProperties;
}

@OnOpen
public void onOpen(String topicId, WebSocketSession session) {
    LOG.info("Open connection for client topic: {}", topicId);
}

@OnMessage
public void onMessage(String topicId, String message, WebSocketSession session) {
    LOG.info("New message from client topic: {}", topicId);
    
    Flowable<ServerHandler> flowable = webSocketClient.connect(ServerHandler.class, connectionProperties.resolveURI(topicId));
    //? so now what to do with this
    // the basic function works, but new connection is created with each message
    //and caching flowable would not be much better than caching WebSocket sessions
    //also it would be nicer to connect in onOpen() and then subscribe in onMessage()

    flowable.subscribe(serverHandler -> {
        serverHandler.setClientSession(session); // register session to send messages back
        serverHandler.send(message); // send message after connection           
    }, t -> LOG.error("Error handling client topic: {}", topicId, t)); //handle exception
}

@OnClose
public void onClose(String topicId) {
    LOG.info("Close connection for client topic: {}", topicId);     
}

@OnError
public void onError(String topicId, WebSocketSession session, Throwable t) {
    LOG.error("Error for client topic: {}", topicId, t);
}
```

}

**Source code ServerHandler:** (Handles WebSocket connection  from router to server)

```
@ClientWebSocket("/topic/{topicId}") public class ServerHandler implements AutoCloseable, WebSocketSessionAware{

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServerHandler.class);

private volatile WebSocketSession clientSession;

private volatile WebSocketSession serverSession;

private volatile String topicId;

@OnOpen
public void onOpen(String topicId, WebSocketSession session) {
    this.topicId = topicId;
    LOG.info("Open connection for server topic: {}", topicId);
}

@OnMessage
public Publisher<String> onMessage(String message) {
    LOG.info("New message from server topic: {}", this.topicId);        
    return clientSession.send(message); //could potentially use WebSocketBroadcaster as well and send to topic based on predicate
}

@OnClose
public void onClose(WebSocketSession session) {
    LOG.info("Close connection for server topic: {}", this.topicId);
    if (clientSession != null) {            
        clientSession.close();
    }
}

@Override
public void close() throws Exception {
    LOG.info("Closing handler for server topic: {}", this.topicId);
}

@Override
public void setWebSocketSession(WebSocketSession serverSession) {
    this.serverSession = serverSession;
}

public void send(String message) {
    if (serverSession == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Can not send if connection not opened");
    }
    serverSession.sendAsync(message); //send message to server
}

public void forceClose() {
    if (serverSession != null) {
        serverSession.close();
    }
}

public void setClientSession(WebSocketSession clientSession) {
    this.clientSession = clientSession;
}
```

}

**Similar existing code**
I searched for similar code in other projects and found snippet of similar functionality in Spring Cloud Gateway (class WebsocketRoutingFilter)
See complete code here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/blob/8722f4062ed21de28ebf56f69bccc5ad4ac1d29d/spring-cloud-gateway-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gateway/filter/WebsocketRoutingFilter.java

This example uses slightly different api with Tomcat WebSocketSession and Reactor library
but anyway again I don't know how to express the similar thing with RxJava Flowable api on top of Micronaut Netty.

```
        return client.execute(url, this.headers, new WebSocketHandler() {
            @Override
            public Mono<Void> handle(WebSocketSession proxySession) {
                // Use retain() for Reactor Netty
                Mono<Void> proxySessionSend = proxySession
                        .send(session.receive().doOnNext(WebSocketMessage::retain));
                // .log("proxySessionSend", Level.FINE);
                Mono<Void> serverSessionSend = session
                        .send(proxySession.receive().doOnNext(WebSocketMessage::retain));
                // .log("sessionSend", Level.FINE);
                return Mono.zip(proxySessionSend, serverSessionSend).then();
            }
```

**Bonus question:**
2) How to handle timeouts and retry of connection with Flowable  ?
If I have code like this:

```
Flowable flowable = serverFlowable.connect(ServerHandler.class, uri);
```

2a) How to connect waiting subscriber which which wants to send message after on connection estabilished  and propagate error if connection attempt fails after given timeout ?
2b) And also how to retry the connection exponentially (5,20, 30 seconds ? ) if connection attempt fails by using RxJava ? I guess repeat() could be used for this ?

Comment: "How can I use the Flowable api which Micronaut to forward messages from ServerHandler to ClientHandler and vice versa ?" - Is `Flowable` a specific requirement for you?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown: It is not strict requirement, just trying to implement this a RxJava conform way, similary to example of Spring Cloud Gateway posted example.  If the api already uses Flowable as a way to subscribe to async events, could make sense to reuse it.